# Batch resize and rename image files in subdirectories

Tags: bash, imagemagick, batch-rename

I'm trying to resize and rename several hundred subdirectories of images. The files that I need to be changed:

- End with A.jpg
- Need to be resized down to 400x400
- Renamed to A@2x.jpg

Example: 
images/**/A6919994719A@2x.jpg

I got the resizing bit down in one directory. I'm having some trouble finding a way to rename just the end of the file, not the extension, and executing it through the subdirectories.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $( ls *A.jpg); do convert -resize 400x400 $i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*A.jpg" | while read f
do
   newname=${f/A.jpg/A@2.jpg}
   echo convert "$f" -resize 400x400 "$newname"
done
```

Remove the word `echo` if it looks correct, and run only on files you have backed up.

You can also do it in a one-liner, if you really want to:

```
find . -name "*A.jpg" -exec bash -c 'old="$0";new=${old/A.jpg/A@2.jpg};echo convert "$old" -resize 400x400 "$new"' {} \;
```